# Weird, squished spacing with "Ask Question" on questions with responsive mobile

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, responsive-design, whitespace

## Update on August 22nd 2019: This glitch has come back:

[image: same glitch as described below]

---

I posted https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331385/399694 yesterday, which got closed, with a very similar bug, but this is not a duplicate of that. This is a new problem, after that fix apparently got implemented.

---

The "Ask Question" button needs more legroom. It's a little cramped at the top of the page:

[image: The button is squished onto the top of the "Asked today" text]

This just looks weird. I think it should just go back to being on the right, like it used to be:

[image]

Maybe the last active and posted times could move under it on small screens? It would still be at the top, but wouldn't need to push the button around.

[image]

Comment: Or just move the asked,viewed,edited to the right of the button. At least on my slightly bigger screen that looks like a plausible space. Wonder how well that would scale...