# “Ask question” takes too much vertical space on questions with responsive mobile, looks bad

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, questions, responsive-design

*Almost all of this text comes from [this previously closed and deleted bug report.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331385/399694) That bug was fixed, but now it’s come back!*

---

Looking at a question, I noticed that the “Ask Question” button by the title has been pushed up a long way:

[image: “Ask Question” in the wrong place]

How it used to look, for comparison:

[image: “Ask Question” in the right place]

This seems to be caused by an overcorrection with a fix to [Weird, squished spacing with "Ask Question" on questions with responsive mobile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331435/399694).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design. With the right question title the columns side by side is preferred. But! There are many question titles that don't look great, especially at `320px`, a breakpoint we support. This doesn't look *that* bad, but can be improved.

[image: Columns]

Of the following possibilities, we went with `C`.

[image: Options]

Comment: The old design worked well, except for with the newly-moved stats. Could it go back to that, putting the stats right under the title, maybe? Thanks for the fast response!

Comment: why not use `float:right` for the button and no float for the title? The text would wrap around the button.

Comment: Yep, that’s another solution. We’ve got a templating issue that prevents us from doing it easily, but I’d like to try this as well.